# vscode snippets not working without a hyphen in tsx files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I've started learning typescript in react an when I want to use snippets(user snippets and extension snippets) in my .tsx files they are not showing up until I use a -(hyphen) in start of line.
this problem not fixed with restarting vscode.

these are the pictures of my problem:

[without hyphen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIImm.png)

[with hyphen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeQuz.png)

Comment: Did you update to vscode v1.75.1 - it may have been fixed there.

Comment: Possibly related: [Visual Studio Code's recent update is disrupting autocompletion](/q/75340072). Also, pretty much the same question here: [VSCode React/Redux snippets don't work in .jsx files](/q/75397268).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with typescript -- worked in .ts files, but not .tsx files.  Fixed the issue and it works as expected now.

Try the following:

1. Go into your snippet file (.json) of interest, copy the entire file into your clipboard

   - Cmd+P > ">Snippets: Configure User Snippets" > *click on your snippets file*
2. Create a new snippet file

   - Cmd+P > ">Snippets: Configure User Snippets" > New Global Snippets File > typescriptreact (enter that for your file name)
3. Paste your old snippet from your clipboard into the new snippet file
4. See if that works out-of-the-box now.
5. If not, add `"scope": "typescriptreact,typescript",` to each of your snippets (e.g. right before "prefix" after the opening bracket)

```
    "comment": {
        "scope": "typescriptreact,typescript",
        "prefix": "comm",
        "body": [
            "{/* ${1:} */}"
        ],
        "description": "comment"
    },
```

I think that should solve it.  (If looking for the answer for JavaScript, do the same steps, but replace every instance of 'typescript' with 'javascript')

On the .ts/.js files, you'll now have duplicates of your snippets, so you'll want to find your old snippets file (.json) and delete it.

*Note:  I tried just adding the "scope" line to my already existing snippets file, but I was getting some sort of linting error saying it wasn't allowed, so I just created a new file following the above steps and there error was no longer present.*